# How to prove that triangle is rectangular

Tags: geometry, triangles

My goal here is to prove that multiplication of segments of tangent line concluded between two straight lines (which are also tangents) are equal to $r^2$. And it's evident if given triangle has a corner of $ 90^\circ$. So i'm trying to find a way to prove that any triangle with a hypotenuse as a tangent line to this circle is rectangular. I think i could draw a median and make a circumcircle around this triangle, but i guess there is some other proof, not only to this, but also to any other tangent by different angle.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the line $CD$ through O perpendicular to the parallel lines: $C$ on the line going through $A$ and $D$ on the line going through $B$. Those parallel lines touch the circle at $C$ and $D$. Also, let $E$ be the point where line $AB$ touches the circle.

We have $\triangle OAC\cong\triangle OAE$ (because $OA=OA, OC=OE, \angle OCA=\angle OEA=90^\circ$) and similarly $\triangle OBD\cong\triangle OBE$.

Thus, $\angle AOE=\angle AOC$ and $\angle BOE=\angle BOD$, so $$\angle AOB=\angle AOE+\angle BOE=\frac{1}{2}(\angle AOC+\angle AOE+\angle BOE+\angle BOD)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 180^\circ=90^\circ$$

Comment: I missed tha fact that it's enought that cathetus and hypotenuse is enough to say triangles are equal. Thans a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Using coordinates, if $O=(0,0), B=(b,-1)$ and the circle has radius $1$, then $A=(1/b,1)$. The vectors $OA$ and $OB$ are clearly orthogonal.

Here is a roadmap.

Let $B=(b,-1)$. A line through $B$ is given by $y+1 = \alpha (x-b)$. Plug this into $x^2+y^2=1$ and get a quadratic equation in $x$. The line is tangent to the circle iff the discriminant is zero. This gives $\alpha=2b/(1-b^2)$. Plugging this and $y=1$ back into the line equation gives $A=(1/b,1)$.